# After changing column type to string, hours, minutes and seconds are missing from the date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am have a dataframe loaded from a file containing a time series and values

```py
      datetime              value_a
0     2019-08-19 00:00:00   194.32000000
1     2019-08-20 00:00:00   202.24000000
2     2019-08-21 00:00:00   196.55000000
3     2019-08-22 00:00:00   187.45000000
4     2019-08-23 00:00:00   190.36000000
```

After I try to convert first column to `string`, the hours minutes and seconds vanish.

```py
     datetime     value_a
0    2019-08-19   194.32000000
1    2019-08-20   202.24000000
2    2019-08-21   196.55000000
3    2019-08-22   187.45000000
4    2019-08-23   190.36000000
```

Code snipped

```py
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].astype(str)
```

I kinda need the format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`, because we are using it later.

What is wrong?

NOTE: I initially though that the issue is during conversion from object to datetime, however thanks to user @SomeDude, I have discovered that I am loosing h/m/s during to string conversion.

Comment: I think its just what you see as printed. After you converted using pd.to_datetime try running `df['datetime'].dt.time`, you will see the times. For dates `df['datetime'].dt.date`

Comment: @SomeDude it seems like... and I have discovered that after converting to string (in order to export), I am loosing hours/minutes/seconds and that is causing the error. `df['datetime'].astype(str)`. That is strange.

Comment: So it seems like that the issue should be "Loosing h/m/s during convertion from datetime to string". I am gonna rephrase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the error can be fixed by using different type conversion method with explicit format definition.

```py
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

This works.

Answer (score 1):

You're saying "I don't like the default format".

Ok. So be explicit, include HMS in it when you re-format.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([dict(datetime='2019-08-19 00:00:00', value_a=194.32)])
>>> df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)
>>> 
>>> df['datetime'] = df.datetime.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
>>> df
              datetime  value_a
0  2019-08-19 00:00:00   194.32
```